# How can I improve my account reputation of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

When I sign up to Stack Overflow, my account has only 1 reputation point, so I can not vote or comment on any question. How do I improve my account reputation points?

BTW: I want to comment on the accepted answer of the question *[Boost asio raw sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022452/boost-asio-raw-sockets/41259001#41259001)*; the accepted answer has something wrong. But I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Hey, welcome on StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 6):

Start with the tour on the top right :)

https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Got it, thank you, ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Hope this link can help you out [Reputation explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: I see, I do my best to answer questions, thanks.

Comment: Ur welcome. Im also new so also checking out some stuff ^^.